# How to show overflow hidden element in div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my application  there are a lot of buttons inside a div.

Initially I am showing three buttons in div width 400 px. Overflow:hidden will hide the remaining elements. I have added below css for div, having right arrow button in my application.
Can anybody body tell how I, if user clicks arrow button, can show next button elements occupying the same width in jquery? If user clicks again I need to show remaining elements up to last element

My html structure is below

```css
.parentdiv {
  display: inline-flex width:400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentdiv">
  <div class="childdiv">
    <span> Text1 
      <button>button1 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="childdiv">
    <span> Text2 lorem ipsum 
      <button>button2 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="childdiv">
    <span> Text3 lorem ipsum 
      <button>button3 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="childdiv">
    <span> Text4 lorem ipsum 
      <button>button4 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="childdiv">
    <span> Text5 lorem ipsum 
      <button>button5 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="childdiv">
    <span> Text6 lorem ipsum 
      <button>button6 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you please provide fiddle link?

Comment: You forgot `"` double quote after "parentdiv"

Comment: You want to show 3 buttons and you are modifying width? Are you sure you have proper code provided because by this Output, i think you should modify height

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is.... a LOT more complicated than you think it is, and will require a **lot** of javascript.

It's usually not worth it to try to reinvent the wheel by hand. The correct solution to accomplish what you want is to use a "**carousel**" plugin. (Many, many different people have created plugins like this. You can simply google for it.)

If you are using Wordpress, then you should search for a Wordpress plugin.

If you simply want a plug-and-play solution that will work with any website, [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) is the best carousel plugin that I know of, and it works great with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Using **jQuery** you can achieve that.
**jQuery library is required**

```
clicked = 1;
divSW = document.getElementByClassName('parentdiv').scrollWidth;
$('button#nxtBtn').click(function(){
    divSL = $('div.parentdiv').scrollLeft();
    if(divSW > divSL){
        clicked++;
        divW = $('div.parentdiv').width();
        moveW = divW * clicked;
        $('div.parentdiv').animate({
            scrollLeft : moveW
        })
    }
})
```

But you need to add a **next button** in your HTML code with an **id** attribute of **nxtBtn**

```
<button id="nxtBtn">next</button>
```

If you need to see the previous buttons in the div you will add another button to your HTML code with an id of **prvBtn**.

```
<button id="prvBtn">previous</button>
```

Then you also add this code below

```
$('button#prvBtn').click(function(){
    divSL = $('div.parentdiv').scrollLeft();
    if(divSL > 0){
        clicked--;
        divW = $('div.parentdiv').width();
        moveW = divW * clicked;
        $('div.parentdiv').animate({
            scrollLeft : moveW
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

```js
$("#after").on("click", function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    $(".childdiv:not(.show)").eq(0).addClass("show");
});
```

```css
#after {
  background: lightgrey;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#after:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.childdiv {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentdiv">
  <div class="childdiv show">
    <span> Text1 
      <button>button1 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="childdiv show">
    <span> Text2 lorem ipsum 
      <button>button2 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="childdiv show">
    <span> Text3 lorem ipsum 
      <button>button3 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="childdiv">
    <span> Text4 lorem ipsum 
      <button>button4 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="childdiv">
    <span> Text5 lorem ipsum 
      <button>button5 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="childdiv">
    <span> Text6 lorem ipsum 
      <button>button6 </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <a id="after">after \/</a>
</div>
```